# Probt in sas for column of values

Tags: sas

Im looking do a probt for a column of values in sas not just one and to give two tailed p values.
I have the following code Id like to amend

```
data all_ssr;
  x=.551447;
  df=25;
  p=(1-probt(abs(x),df))*2;
  put p=;
run;
```

however I would like x to be a column of values within another file. I have tried work.ttest which is just a file of ttest values.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a set statement to access data from another SAS dataset.

```
data all_ssr;
  set work.ttest; /*Dataset containing column of values*/
  df=25;
  p=(1-probt(abs(x),df))*2;
run;
```

Removing the `put` statement avoids clogging up the log.

Comment: Thank you that works. I thought I had tried that before but must have went wrong somewhere

Comment: Also if you know how I could clear the log while running this is that would be great- I have 16 million observations. I have tried putting dm 'output;clear;log;clear;'; before the run statement, after the run statement and before the whole statement. Thanks!

Comment: why are you using put p= while you're asking for clearing log windows?
isn't it easier to check for your p-s on the data dataset (all_ssr in this case)?